# could not find libsocket.so and libintl.so

Tags: c

I am trying to compile some tools which used to analyze HTTP logs, when ever I type make getting following error and I am not able to locate libsocket.so and libintl.so in my file system,

```
gcc -o showtrace showtrace.o logparse.o utils.o -lsocket -lnsl -lintl -ldl -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsocket
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lintl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

how to solve this problem please help.

Comment: Are these packages installed on your system?

Comment: no i think, how to install these packages?

Comment: With your system's tool for installing packages or from sources. (Also, are you sure these libraries are even required for your system? )

Comment: @larsmans Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Q belongs to Ubuntu@stackexchange (where the ubuntu experts are)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not really sure about `libintl`, but `libsocket` is a library that only exists on System V-style Unixes (e.g. Solaris, HP-UX). If you're on Linux or a BSD-derivative (that includes Mac OS X), then you don't need to link to `libsocket` because sockets are implemented in `libc` which is linked in by default. Try linking without `-lsocket` and `-lintl`.